# javascript remove g from regex

Tags: javascript, regex

Sometimes I need to use regex with g and sometimes without g.

```
let setreg = /set (\w+) (.+?)/g;
let setregnog = /set (\w+) (.+?)/;
```

Is there a way to just add a g to the end of setreg instead of using 2 vars.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adding modifiers to an existing regular expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9437203/adding-modifiers-to-an-existing-regular-expression)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes - you can use the `RegExp()` constructor.

```
let ptn = /foo/;
new RegExp(ptn, 'g'); //<-- with
new RegExp(ptn); //<-- without
```